# What does this gradle/groovy structure mean?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm reading an android gradle build file and I don't understand how some of it works from a syntax perspective and could do with some guidance. I've looked at the gradle and the groovy docs and can't find what I need. To be honest, I don't even know what to search for.

The structure in question is this:

```
name {
  ...
}
```

I suspect that it's something to do with closures, but I really don't know what's going on here. This structure is embedded in another identical structure. What are these things, and how are they invoked/read/used by the interpreter?

Comment: yes its calling the function `name` with the closure passed.  like `name({ ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  This is a closure, that gets called as parameter to the method `name`.

Like

```
 name({ /*...*/ })
```

[See the docs for when to leave out parentheses](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_optional_parentheses).

The method `name` must not really exist in that context as this is a widely used pattern in groovy DSLs. [`methodMissing`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_methodmissing) will be called instead.